# Maven JavaDoc plugin giving warnings instead of Errors

Tags: maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

i have added maven java doc plugin dependency in my pox.xml as below

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And using java version 1.8, but its throwing warnings instead of errors when comments are missing or when there is no description.
i want it to throw errors, can any one please help with this? Thanks in advance!
It was throwing the below warnings in the console

```
7 warnings
[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings
[WARNING] javadoc: warning - Multiple sources of package comments found for package "javax.servlet"
[WARNING] javadoc: warning - Multiple sources of package comments found for package "javax.servlet.http"
[WARNING] C:\SOFTDEV\LPIS\LPISDEPT\WEBAPP\branches\DEVELOPMENT\web\lpis_web\src\main\java\ie\gov\agriculture\lpis\web\auth\servlet\LPISAuthenticationServlet.java:61: warning: no description for @throws
[WARNING] * @throws IOException
[WARNING] ^
[WARNING] C:\SOFTDEV\LPIS\LPISDEPT\WEBAPP\branches\DEVELOPMENT\web\lpis_web\src\main\java\ie\gov\agriculture\lpis\web\editcache\filter\attribute\EditFilterAttribute.java:32: warning: no description for @param
[WARNING] * @param currentEntityFilter
[WARNING] ^
[WARNING] C:\SOFTDEV\LPIS\LPISDEPT\WEBAPP\branches\DEVELOPMENT\web\lpis_web\src\main\java\ie\gov\agriculture\lpis\web\editcache\filter\factory\EntityFilter.java:19: warning: no description for @param
[WARNING] * @param projectId
[WARNING] ^
[WARNING] C:\SOFTDEV\LPIS\LPISDEPT\WEBAPP\branches\DEVELOPMENT\web\lpis_web\src\main\java\ie\gov\agriculture\lpis\web\editcache\filter\factory\EntityFilter.java:20: warning: no description for @param
[WARNING] * @param attributeValues
[WARNING] ^
[WARNING] C:\SOFTDEV\LPIS\LPISDEPT\WEBAPP\branches\DEVELOPMENT\web\lpis_web\src\main\java\ie\gov\agriculture\lpis\web\editcache\filter\factory\FilterFactory.java:40: warning: no description for @param
[WARNING] * @param parameter
[WARNING] ^
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to set error to fail the build, you can also use failOnWarnings.

Form more informations see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#failOnWarnings

```
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
                            <configuration>
                                 <failOnWarnings>true</failOnWarnings>
                            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```